# Extract suffix from a single line in a multiline string in groovy matching a prefix

Tags: regex, groovy

In groovy I have these two multi-line strings:

```
String input1 = """\
    test: task ':test'
    version: 1.1.0.1
    targetCompatibility: 1.8        
""".stripIndent()

String input2 = """\
    test: task ':test'
    version: latest
    testResultsDirName: test-results
    targetCompatibility: 1.8        
""".stripIndent()
```

I need extract whatever text comes after `version:` and have come up with this method:

```
String getProjectVersion(String input, String prefix){
    String result = "Unknown"
    if (input.contains(prefix)) {
        def list = input.readLines()
        def all = list.findAll { s -> s =~ prefix }[0]
        result = all - prefix
    }
    return result
}
```

Which given the above input:

```
String prefix = "version:"
println getProjectVersion(input1, prefix)
println getProjectVersion(input2, prefix)
```

prints:

```
1.1.0.1
latest
```

which is great!

But is there a more compact way of achieving the same *without* creating special regex patterns that can probably do everything in one-line but becomes impossible to understand for the regex uninitiated?

Comment: Do you ask how to get what you need without regex, or with a simple regex? It can be done [with a simple regex](https://ideone.com/nHUOGu), sure.

Comment: Preferably without regex but also a "clean" regex could be nice to see.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you can use a very simple regex to extract the string after the word `version:` using

```
String getProjectVersion(String input){
    def m = input =~ /version:\h*(.+)/
    if (m) {
      return m.group(1);
    }
    return "Unknown"
}
```

See the [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/nHUOGu).

Here, `version:\h*(.+)` pattern matches `version:`, then any zero or more horizontal whitespaces (so that you stay on the same line) and then *captures* into Group 1 (see `m.group(1)`) any one or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (with `(.+)`).

If Group 1 matched, the return value is the Group 1 value, else, the return value is `Unknown`.

Answer (score 1):

if you are going to take different values from same input - it's better to convert input to Map object that could be accessed faster

```
String input1 = """\
    test: task ':test'
    version: 1.1.0.1
    targetCompatibility: 1.8        
    #
""".stripIndent()


def toMap(String s){
    def p = /(\w+):\s*(.*)/
    s.readLines().collect{it=~p}.findAll{it}.collectEntries{ [ it[0][1], it[0][2].trim()]}
}

def m1 = toMap(input1)

println m1.version
println m1.test
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could read the data in the format, that it is: YAML from the looks of it.

```
println(new groovy.yaml.YamlSlurper().parseText(input1)["version"])
// → latest
```